# How can a write a SQL query to print a detail where all fields are identical in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Brc act code
101 0 20
101 0 21
101 1 22
101 0 22
```

I want to print only entry of 22 code where act is 1 and skip the 0 entry of code 22 and print the rest all other rows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to retrieve the "last version for each code". If that's the case, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify it. Then, filtering is easy.

For example:

```
select brc, act, code
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by code order by act desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 BRC  ACT  CODE 
 ---- ---- ---- 
 101  0    20   
 101  0    21   
 101  1    22
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0100ee0deb6007ae56d999f092cb836a).